# Calculating Gas Remaining at Specific Point in Execution of Contract

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-estimate

This is a doozy :~)

I'm trying to figure out the amount of gas remaining in some contract at some specific step. For example:

`function hash(uint num) returns (bytes32) {
        return sha3(num, msg.gas);
}`

While this is a silly example, for all intents and purposes, I want to be able to calculate what this function will return before I have to make a call/interact with a node.

I know that the amount of gas at this step is determined by how much gas I initially provide, the data in the actual call (aka, if the num provided has a bunch of zeros), etc.

How can I calculate the hash generated by this tx before interacting with a node in anway? I imagine there is some formula - maybe it relies on me reading the VM code and/or byte code.

Also, I guess, these are sub-questions to this question:

1. Is gas deducted before an operation is performed?
2. Is there a generalized way to calculate the gas remaining at a specific point in the execution of a contract?

Any info (or just a point in the right direction) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!